# Spring Data JPA Deletes Child Entity Only When Parent is LAZY Fetched

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have a user class which has a field:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JsonManagedReference
private Set<FavoriteProduct> favoriteProducts = new HashSet<>();
```

Favorite product class has that field:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "users_id", nullable = false)
@JsonBackReference
private User user;
```

When I try to delete a favorite product via a favorite product repository which extends a `JpaRepository` it is not successfull.

However, it works when I change `EAGER` fetch to `LAZY` fetch as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "users_id", nullable = false)
@JsonBackReference
private User user;
```

What can be the reason for that?

Answer (score 1):

- Hibernate will not delete a child object if that object is referenced from a parent object.
- With `FetchType.EAGER`, you are initializing the association with the parent too.
- With `FetchType.LAZY`, the `user` association will not be loaded unless you try to access the user in the persistence context.
- You can try to access the `user` first before deleting. It should emulate the similar behavior even with `FetchType.LAZY`

Comment: Could you eloborate this part: You can try to access the user first before deleting. It should emulate the similar behavior even with FetchType.LAZY

Comment: On the other hand, why not cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true effects in such case?